# How can I make a in interactive list in Python's Tkinter complete with buttons that can edit those listings?

Tags: python, user-interface, listbox, tkinter, interactive

Basically I want there to be a list, which displays files I have stored in a certain folder, and beside the list there are buttons which open up separate windows which can edit or add a new item to that list.

I want addchar to open up an new window with spaces for different fields, then when you press a "create" button in that window it closes, creates a file on the info you just entered (that's why i've imported os) as well as creating a new item on the main interface's listbox as the name of the character (which is one of the fields). The removechar function would remove that entry and delete the file, and editchar would open up a window similar to addchar, but with the info of the selected item on the list.

EDIT: Here's the code so far

```
from tkinter import *
import os
import easygui as eg

class App:

    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        # character box
        Label(frame, text = "Characters Editor").grid(row = 0, column = 0, rowspan = 1, columnspan = 2)
        charbox = Listbox(frame)
        for chars in []:
            charbox.insert(END, chars)
        charbox.grid(row = 1, column = 0, rowspan = 5)
        charadd = Button(frame, text = "   Add   ", command = self.addchar).grid(row = 1, column = 1)
        charremove = Button(frame, text = "Remove", command = self.removechar).grid(row = 2, column = 1)
        charedit = Button(frame, text = "    Edit    ", command = self.editchar).grid(row = 3, column = 1)

    def addchar(self):
        print("not implemented yet")
    def removechar(self):
        print("not implemented yet")
    def editchar(self):
        print("not implemented yet")


root = Tk()
root.wm_title("IA Development Kit")
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why don't you try writing a program that does this, then ask here when you get stuck?  Or if you've already tried to work this out, post the code you've written so we can help you.

Comment: Sorry about that. I put the code in.

Comment: No prob, glad you gave it a try first.  Is your question "how do I implement addchar, removechar, and editchar"?  If so, could you clarify exactly what you want them to do?  You've said something about displaying files in a directory, and something about opening separate windows, but I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: I want addchar to open up an new window with spaces for different fields, then when you press a "create" button in that window it closes, creates a file on the info you just entered (that's why i've imported os) as well as creating a new item on the main interface's listbox as the name of the character (which is one of the fields). The removechar function would remove that entry and delete the file, and editchar would open up a window similar to addchar, but with the info of the selected item on the list. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I implemented `addchar` and `removechar` for you (and tweaked a few other things in your code).  I'll leave the implementation of `editchar` to you - take a look at what I wrote to help you, as well as the [listbox documentation](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/listbox.htm)

```
from Tkinter import *  # AFAIK Tkinter is always capitalized
#import os
#import easygui as eg

class App:
    characterPrefix = "character_"
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master  # You'll want to keep a reference to your root window
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        # character box
        Label(frame, text = "Characters Editor").grid(row = 0, column = 0, rowspan = 1, columnspan = 2)
        self.charbox = Listbox(frame)  # You'll want to keep this reference as an attribute of the class too.
        for chars in []:
            self.charbox.insert(END, chars)
        self.charbox.grid(row = 1, column = 0, rowspan = 5)
        charadd = Button(frame, text = "   Add   ", command = self.addchar).grid(row = 1, column = 1)
        charremove = Button(frame, text = "Remove", command = self.removechar).grid(row = 2, column = 1)
        charedit = Button(frame, text = "    Edit    ", command = self.editchar).grid(row = 3, column = 1)

    def addchar(self, initialCharacter='', initialInfo=''):
        t = Toplevel(root)  # Creates a new window
        t.title("Add character")
        characterLabel = Label(t, text="Character name:")
        characterEntry = Entry(t)
        characterEntry.insert(0, initialCharacter)
        infoLabel = Label(t, text="Info:")
        infoEntry = Entry(t)
        infoEntry.insert(0, initialInfo)
        def create():
            characterName = characterEntry.get()
            self.charbox.insert(END, characterName)
            with open(app.characterPrefix + characterName, 'w') as f:
                    f.write(infoEntry.get())
            t.destroy()
        createButton = Button(t, text="Create", command=create)
        cancelButton = Button(t, text="Cancel", command=t.destroy)

        characterLabel.grid(row=0, column=0)
        infoLabel.grid(row=0, column=1)
        characterEntry.grid(row=1, column=0)
        infoEntry.grid(row=1, column=1)
        createButton.grid(row=2, column=0)
        cancelButton.grid(row=2, column=1)

    def removechar(self):
        for index in self.charbox.curselection():
            item = self.charbox.get(int(index))
            self.charbox.delete(int(index))
            try:
                os.remove(characterPrefix + item)
            except IOError:
                print "Could not delete file", characterPrefix + item
    def editchar(self):
        # You can implement this one ;)

root = Tk()
root.wm_title("IA Development Kit")
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: No prob, hope it helps :)

Comment: Oh, and, my pyton 3.3 cannot process Tkinter capitalised. It has to be tkinter.

Comment: Ummm, the part where it goes characterName = characterEntry.get() doesn't seem to work. does this have something to do with initialCharacter?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out that separating the grid commands from the commands that make the widgets solved it. Thanks, anyway :)