# Python: Tkinter: Why is it root.mainloop() and not app.mainloop()

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

I'm a new member to Stack Overflow.
I found this thread, but was not allowed to comment or ask questions on it, so I thought I'd just reference it here: [How can I make a in interactive list in Python's Tkinter complete with buttons that can edit those listings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18201195/how-can-i-make-a-in-interactive-list-in-pythons-tkinter-complete-with-buttons-t)

```
from tkinter import *
import os
import easygui as eg

class App:

    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        # character box
        Label(frame, text = "Characters Editor").grid(row = 0, column = 0, rowspan = 1, columnspan = 2)
        charbox = Listbox(frame)
        for chars in []:
            charbox.insert(END, chars)
        charbox.grid(row = 1, column = 0, rowspan = 5)
        charadd = Button(frame, text = "   Add   ", command = self.addchar).grid(row = 1, column = 1)
        charremove = Button(frame, text = "Remove", command = self.removechar).grid(row = 2, column = 1)
        charedit = Button(frame, text = "    Edit    ", command = self.editchar).grid(row = 3, column = 1)

    def addchar(self):
        print("not implemented yet")
    def removechar(self):
        print("not implemented yet")
    def editchar(self):
        print("not implemented yet")


root = Tk()
root.wm_title("IA Development Kit")
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Could somebody explain to me why the very last line is root.mainloop()?
Being a novice with Python, and coming from a background that's procedural-oriented with no object-orient experience, I would have thought it would have been app.mainloop().

In fact app = App(root) , app is never used again in the rest of the code! I'm having trouble understanding why root.mainloop() still works.

Comment: So when you initialize your `App` class with `root`, the `__init__` function is run, in which all of the GUI components are loaded. `mainloop` is a method of `Tk` which starts the event loop of the window. We therefore have no need to re-reference the `class` (although technically we do, inside the `class` itself) because everything we need is done when we initialize that `class`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure if you'll find this answer satisfying, but you call `root.mainloop()` because `root` is the object that has the `mainloop` method. In the code you've given, `App` has no `mainloop` function.

In simpler terms, this is just how tkinter works -- you always end your script by calling the `mainloop` method of the root window. When that method returns, your program will exit.

Let's start at the beginning. The simplest, non-OO Tkinter program is going to look like the following example. Note that this is a python 2.x example, and I do not use a global import since I think global imports are bad.

```
import Tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
<your widgets go here>
root.mainloop()
```

Many people find that a pure procedural style is not an effective way to write code, so they might choose to write this in an object-oriented style. It's natural to think of "the app" as a singleton object. There are many ways to do this -- the one in your question is, unfortunately, not one of the clearer ways to do it.

A slightly better way, IMO, would be to structure the code like this:

```
class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        <your widgets go here>
app = App()
app.mainloop()
```

In this case, `mainloop` is still being called, though now it's a method of `App` since `App` inherits from `Tk`. It is conceptually the same as `root.mainloop()` since in this case, `app` *is* the root window even though it goes by a different name.

So, in both cases, `mainloop` is a method that belongs to the root window. And in both cases, it must be called for the GUI to function properly.

There is a third variation which is what the code you picked is using. And with this variation, there are several ways to implement it. The variation is your question uses a class to define the GUI, but does *not* inherit from `Tk`. This is perfectly fine, but you still must call `mainloop` at some point. Since you don't create (or inherit) a `mainloop` function in your class, you must call the one associated with the root window. The variations I speak of are how and where the instance of `App` is added to the root window, and how `mainloop` is ultimately called.

Personally I prefer that `App` inherits from `Frame`, and that you pack the app *outside* the definition of the app. The template I use looks like this:

```
class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        <your widgets go here>

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(root)
    app.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

In this final example, `app` and `root` are two completely different objects. `app` represents a frame that exists *inside* the root window. Frames are commonly used this way, as a container for groups of other widgets.

So, in all cases, `mainloop` must be called. *where* it is called, and how, depends a bit on your coding style. Some people prefer to inherit from the root window, some don't. In either case, you must call the `mainloop` function of the root window.

Comment: (Excuse me because I'm potentially going to butcher the use of terminology.)
This answer is satisfying enough. I guess what I'm really tripped up by is when all is said and done, is app and root one and the same instance of an object?
Coming from a procedural background, if app and root are DIFFERENT instances, all the widgets are packed into the app instance. So if I called root.mainloop() I would not expect to see the newly packed widgets. But if I called app.mainloop(), intuitively it makes sense to me to see all the packed widgets.
But I'm surmising that app and root are the same instance.

Comment: And because app and root are the same instance, anything packed into app is also visible in root, so in the end, root.mainloop() will show all the widgets that were packed into app.

Comment: @Nuuk: in the final example, app and root are two _different_ objects. root is the root window into which all other widgets go. It is an instance of the class Tk, and every tkinter application must have exactly one instance of this class. app is an instance of the class App, which is a subclass of Frame. A frame is typically used as a container for other widgets, in this case the widgets that make up the app (except for the root window). This frame is packed inside the root window. app and root are two completely different things. root is a container for app.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for that elegant explanation. That made all the difference. Now I know Frame and Tk are two completely different classes. Everything is starting to make more sense. I think what's next for me is to learn Python classes, how subclasses work, inheritance, etc. I believe that's where all the confusion arose. You see, when I saw `app = App(root)`, I thought that meant that app was a subclass of root, and root is an instance of the class Tk. But you answered my question quite elegantly, and pointed out the real problem: I simply need to learn Python classes.

Answer (score 1):

I tested both like you see:

One is written with **"app." + ".pack()"** and one calls **"mainframe." + ".grid()"**

```
 #-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#THIS IS THE "MAINFRAME." - PART
from Tkinter import *
import ttk

def show():
    p = password.get() #get password from entry
    print(p)


root = Tk()
root.title("Ingos first program")

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="30 30 60 12")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)


password = StringVar() #Password variable
passEntry = Entry(mainframe, textvariable=password, show='*').grid(column=3, row=3, sticky=S)
submit = Button(mainframe, text='Show Console',command=show).grid(column=3, row=4, sticky=S)

root.mainloop()
def show():
    p = password.get() #get password from entry
    print(p)

#THIS IS THE "APP."-PART. BOTH WORKS FINE.
app = Tk()
app.title("Ingos first program")
password = StringVar() #Password variable
passEntry = Entry(app, textvariable=password, show='#').pack()
submit = Button(app, text='Show Console',command=show).pack()

app.mainloop()
```

This instance works fine with python 2.7. In that test even app. can handle "mainloop()"
That script opens 2 windows, one after another (if you close the first one) and the first programm is formatted, didn't tryed to write the colum=3... stuff in the pack() clamps.

I still started the Tkinter so don't fight me, just trying.. Hope I could help to answer your question.
All the best, Ingo

Answer (score 0):

The `App` object is just your app code, and the reason you call `App(root)` is to make an instance with your class, which then has access to your root window.

It receives this reference in the `__init__` method:

```
def __init__(self, master):
    # master refers to the root window now
    ...
```

You can see the entire definition of the `App` object (given by the block beginning with `class App:`), and it doesn't even have a `mainloop` method, so to start the main Tkinter loop, you have to call it on the root window.

In the [example in the Python2 documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html#a-simple-hello-world-program), they *do* call it as you suspected should be done, but note that their example class subclasses the Tk object `Frame`. In your example code, `App` is an old-style class that doesn't inherit anything.

Comment: I don't think the words you used are a little unclear. The reason you call `App(root)` is not "to save a reference" but rather to actually create the app. The only thing that saves the reference is when you assign the result to the variable `app`. So, again, you don't _call_ it to save the reference, you _assign it to a variable_ to save the reference.

Comment: I meant the reason you call `App` with `root` as a parameter, but I guess I see what you mean.

Comment: You're still getting it wrong. You don't call it with root as a parameter in order to save a reference. You call it with root as a parameter because the App class requires you tell it what window it is to be created in.

Comment: I still think we're just talking past each other, but I adjusted the wording. The App class needs to have the window passed in so it can use it (to tell it what window it is to be created in and possibly other uses depending on the functionality of app) is the point I'm trying to make.

Comment: As you can all see, my object-oriented knowledge is still limited.
My understanding is
`root.mainloop()`
is the main GUI window that gets displayed. Then
`app = App(root)`
is where we create an instance of the App class, but app never gets used anywhere else in the code. Yet, by creating the instance of the App class, everything in the
`def __init__(self, master):`
of app is suddenly visible on the main GUI window (root.mainloop()).
If this is the wrong place to ask (because I really know zero object-oriented programming), I'll be happy to be redirected to other discussions that may explain.