# Why does Python tkinter crash when opening this file?

Tags: python, tkinter, terminal, crash, launcher

Anyone know why Python Launcher crashes when running this code? Is there something obvious I am missing as it was working before. Running on Mac from terminal.

Doesn't even throw an error, so I'm not really sure what is going on.

Do I need to update tkinter or is it just one of the functions that is casuing an issue?

```
import tkinter as tk
import requests
import json
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("800x600")
# root.configure(bg = 'black')

# root.iconbitmap('./images/rain_jpeg.jpg')

Images = dict()

def display_photo(row=0, column=0):

    if weather_main + '_tk' not in [*Images]:
        image_1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("./images/" + weather_main + ".jpg"))
        photo = tk.Label(root, image = image_1)
        photo.image = image_1
        photo.pack()

    text_runner()

def city_clicker_runner():
    
    global weather_main
    global city

    city = e.get()
    request_address = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + city + "&units=metric&appid=0a0699452f695d2f9f82b65af024a134"
    api_request = requests.get(request_address)
    api = json.loads(api_request.content)

    mylabel2 = tk.Label(root, text = 'URL=' + request_address)
    # mylabel2.configure(foreground="white")
    mylabel2.pack()

    coordinates = api["coord"]
    weather_main = api["weather"][0]["main"]
    weather_description = api["weather"][0]["description"]
    temp = int(api["main"]["temp"])

    mainy = tk.Label(root, text = "the weather is " + weather_main)
    mainy.pack()

    display_photo()
        
def text_runner():

    running = tk.Label(root, text = 'we are running')
    running.pack()

    mylabel = tk.Label(root, text = "The weather in " + city + " is " + weather_main + " and the temperature is " + str(temp), font=("Helvetica", 20))
    mylabel.pack()

e = tk.Entry(root)
e.pack()

city_clicker = tk.Button(root, text = "GO", command=city_clicker_runner)
city_clicker.pack()
```

Comment: Where is your `root.mainloop()` ?

Comment: That doesn't look like a [mre] at all.

Comment: Wow, I am an idiot, thank you so much aha.

Comment: @BenjaminMcDowell Ive added an answer, if you could mark it as the answer it would close the Q

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Tkinter: Why is it root.mainloop() and not app.mainloop()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22698980/python-tkinter-why-is-it-root-mainloop-and-not-app-mainloop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without `root.mainloop()` the app wont start. Its like the app is always closed, you have to keep it inside of a loop for it to actually keep running as long as you close it(break out of the loop)

Hope it cleared the error

Cheers